Python code to generate batching process of chat completion calls with Azure OpenAI to Azure AI endpoint
I am working Azure OpenAI. I have successfully completed the chat completions using python code. I read through following code to implement batching process to reduce the cost. I have a bunch of unimportant tasks that can wait to get processed. So, reading the following document, I thought to implement batching process. However, I dont find the python code for this. Request to share if someone can show me the pointers.


I found answer, here is the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/how-to/batch?tabs=standard-input&pivots=programming-language-python#region-and-model-support

Please add this as an answer and accept it. so, that it will help the community to find better solution

How do I do that?

There is a option below where you can write the answer.

I found answer, here is the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/how-to/batch?tabs=standard-input&pivots=programming-language-python#region-and-model-support
